# Filtrar valor de array

Tags: php, array

Minha array será:

```
$arr = array();

while($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

    $arr = array('cnpj' => $r['cnpj'], 'empresa' => $r['nome']);

}
```

No while, existem vários resultados (CNPJ repetidos), e gostaria de montar a array com apenas um indice para cada CNPJ, e não criar diversos indices com o mesmo CPNJ repetido, se existir 5 CNPJ no WHILE, guardar apenas uma vez O CNPJ.

**Gostaria de saber como verificar se já existe o CNPJ na array antes de inserí-lo.**

PS: Estou gerando um array à partir de um while(), não estou querendo remover valor duplicado de um array existente.

Comment: É valor, não índice, editei a pergunta.

Comment: Coloque mais informações não ficou claro o que você precisar fazer. Entendi que tente comparar os dados porém não entendi a lógica, por favor explique melhor para podermos ajudar.

Comment: essa variavel `$arr` seria para guardar o array? ou seja, não seria `$arr[]` ?

Comment: Resolve isso na sua SQL !!!

Comment: É um procedure de terceiro, estou implementando o PHP apenas, e não tenho acesso ao procedure, apenas recebo a lista de procedures.

Comment: Discordo, o que necessito é gerar um array, não remover duplicata de um array existente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com todos os dados e mensagens que não dá para resolver na [sql](/questions/tagged/sql), então faça assim:

```
$arr = array();

while($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{    
    $b = $r['cnpj'];
    if (count(array_filter($arr, function($a) use($b)  { return $b == $a['cnpj'];}))==0) 
    {
        $arr[] = array('cnpj' => $r['cnpj'], 'empresa' => $r['nome']);    
    }
}
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [in_array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php)
- [array_values](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php)
- [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: @EliseuB. troquei a função... dá uma olhada agora

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Grato!

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de resolver esse problema é combinar [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) para saber se o cnpj já existe no array ou não. Para que a comparação seja feita de forma correta use [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) essa função extrai todos valores de subindice.

```
$arr = array();
while($r = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if(!in_array($r['cnpj'], array_column($arr, 'cnpj'))){
       $arr[] = $r;
    }
}
```

O array original tem mais ou menos essa estrutura:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [empresa] => AAA
            [cnpj] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [empresa] => BBB
            [cnpj] => 3
        )
)
```

Com a chamade `array_column($arr, 'cnpj')` ele é transformado para:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)
```

**[Exemplo - repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CruelCarefreeGoral)**

Answer (score 1):

Você também pode efetuar a junção das funções [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) e [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php):

```
$fromSQL = [
    [
        'empresa' => 'abc',
        'cnpj' => 72905498000142
    ],
    [
        'empresa' => 'abc',
        'cnpj' => 72905498000142
    ],
    [
        'empresa' => 'ghi',
        'cnpj' => 21808437000126
    ],
    [
        'empresa' => 'jkl',
        'cnpj' => 19107168000129
    ],
    [
        'empresa' => 'mno',
        'cnpj' => 65566224000100
    ]
];
```

Você teria o resultado:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'abc' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 72905498000142
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'abc' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 72905498000142
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'ghi' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 21808437000126
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'jkl' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 19107168000129
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'mno' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 65566224000100
```

Aplicando o `map` com `unique`:

```
$arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $fromSQL)));
```

Resultaria em:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'abc' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 72905498000142
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'ghi' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 21808437000126
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'jkl' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 19107168000129
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      'empresa' => string 'mno' (length=3)
      'cnpj' => int 65566224000100
```